# Jetpack Compose Lazy Table

Tags: android, android-layout, android-jetpack-compose

My current goal is to achieve a view that can represent a table, but this table can contain quite a few elements in its columns and rows. My current idea is to populate `LazyColumn` with `LazyRows`.

```
@Composable
internal fun Table() {
    
    LazyColumn {
        items(count = 100) {
            LazyRow {
                items(10) {
                    Box(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .size(100.dp)
                            .border(width = 1.dp, color = Color.Black)
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

But there is a huge problem: I don't want the rows to be able to scroll by themselves, I want any scrolling to be shared. Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to achieve that. As far as I know lazy grid can't help me either.

I also tried to use the same instance of `LazyListState`, but it doesn't work.

Comment: i guess you can use one single `scrollState` for all of your `LazyRow`s
if you are not able to do this tell me to give you a sample

Comment: what if you use the same scrollState for all the rows?

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

There is now a cool library called [LazyTable](https://github.com/oleksandrbalan/lazytable) which is based on LazyLayout

Answer (score 0):

In a new version appered new layout called "LazyLayout" - it's somewhat of your custom lazy layout builder. This should solve my problem, although i haven't tried it yet